# Passing arraylist in querystring in java?

Tags: java, php, query-string

I encoded an image to string and put that in arraylist. how can i send that arraylist throw querystring to server and get that arraylist in a php?

Is it possible to send arraylist in querystring?

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Why do you have a list of strings? What does your data look like?

Comment: You will have to convert into `byte[]` values to send the data. Else the data would be lost and the file may be corrupted in transit.

Comment: are you programming from a servlet to a php web page? maybe you mean javascript instead of Java?

Comment: thanks for ur fast comments..... Actually what i did means
`Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCameraFileName);
ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmapOrg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);
final byte [] ba = bao.toByteArray();
final String ba1= Base64.encodeBytes(ba);
setImageValuePairs(ba1);`
first i convert to bytes and encoded with base64 and assigned in string. And finally i put that string in a arraylist. now i want to send that in querystring?? my first question is, is it possible to send arraylist in querystring???

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON to represent array of strings. You can represent the entire list as a JSON object and send across in the querystring.

Comment: Pls give coding to represent array string as JSON and send throw querystring... plsssss.. very urgent